# How do I add a time delay to a Python instance method?

Tags: python, multithreading, testing, concurrency, sleep

I want to write good tests to make sure my concurrent data structure works. But the tests are passing even on a class that is obviously not thread-safe.

```
class NotThreadSafe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.set1 = set()
        self.set2 = set()

    def add_to_sets(self, item):
        self._add_to_set1(item)
        self._add_to_set2(item)

    def _add_to_set1(self, item):
        self.set1.add(item)

    def _add_to_set2(self, item):
        self.set2.add(item)

    def are_sets_equal_length(self):
        return len(self.set1) == len(self.set2)
```

My tests have a reader thread and a writer thread running concurrently. The writer thread calls `add_to_sets` and the reader thread calls `are_sets_equal_length`.

But the reader thread always observes `are_sets_equal_length` to be True, even though the writer thread should theoretically cause inequalities.

How can I add some time delay on `add_to_set2` so that it forces the race condition to surface?

The test:

```
import threading
import time

def writer_fn(nts: NotThreadSafe):
    for i in range(1000):
        nts.add_to_sets(i)

def reader_fn(nts: NotThreadSafe, stop: list, results: list):
    while not len(stop):
        if not nts.are_sets_equal_length():
            results.append(False)
            return
    results.append(True)


def test_nts():
    nts = NotThreadSafe()
    stop = []
    results = []
    reader = threading.Thread(target=reader_fn, args=[nts, stop, results])
    writer = threading.Thread(target=writer_fn, args=[nts])
    reader.start()
    writer.start()
    writer.join()
    stop.append(True)
    reader.join()
    assert not results[0]
```

Comment: you can use thread locks where necessary. This page gives a solid overview of how to use them and what they do. If you want how to use them, scroll down the page a bit. --> https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-threading-lock/

Comment: @Mitchnoff the question is about writing tests that reveal non-thread safe code.

Comment: Interesting question, I usually find non thread-safe code by comparing the results in serial vs. parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: write a wrapper that creates a new function containing a time delay.

```
def slow_wrapper(method):
    """Adds a tiny delay to a method. Good for triggering race conditions that would otherwise be very rare."""
    def wrapped_method(*args):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        return method(*args)
    return wrapped_method
```

Step 2: In the test function, after creating the object, change `add_to_set2` into a slow version:

```
nts = NotThreadSafe()

# change _add_to_set2 into a time-delayed version
nts._add_to_set2 = slow_wrapper(nts._add_to_set2)
```

Step 3: Run the tests. The failure should be triggered properly.